# Assign value to attribute based on condition

Tags: angularjs

I need to set max value for input field as 250 or 500 based on condition.

I have a ng-modal {{info.temp}} which contains value 1 or 0.

Based on this, if value is 1 the max number that can be entered in text box is 250 or else 500.

Please let me know how to write this logic in angularjs in HTML

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some code examples. set condition to the number field use `ng-max` directive  .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="form1">
      condition input: <input type="text" ng-init="condition=1" ng-model="condition" /> <br/> final input: <input name="result" type="number" ng-max="condition == '0' ? 250 : 500" ng-model="result" /> {{result }} <span ng-show="form1.result.$invalid"> Final input not valid</span>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But ng-max is not throwing form error when it exceeds limt.                           ng-show="form.input.$error

Comment: please set proper name to form and input. `ng-show="form1.result.$invalid"`

Comment: <ng-form name="Form1">
<input  type="number"  name="infotemperature" ng-model="info.temp" class="form-control" ng-required  ng-max="info.tempUnit == 1?500:250">{{info.temp > 500}}. When i use input type as number, the value {{info.temp > 500}} is not getting compared

Comment: `ng-max="info.tempUnit == '1' ? 500 : 250"` . set 1 as a string '1'. run my edited code snippet

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

run this code and you should change temp with edit and run again :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <label for="maxlength">Set a Info.Temp 0 or 1 : </label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="info.temp" id="maxlength" />
    <br>
    <label for="input">This input is restricted by the current Info.temp 1 = 250 and 0 = 500 char : </label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" id="input" name="input" ng-maxlength="info.temp ? 250 : 500" /><br>
    <hr>
    input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
    model = <code>{{name}}</code>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.info = { temp : 1};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```